# jquery ajax: read value from CGI

Tags: jquery, ajax, cgi

i'm trying to get a value from a CGI with jquery ajax. i can't change any settings of the CGI because it's not on my own server.

all i know about the CGI is that if i directly tape this in a browser address bar:

"http://otherdomain/cgi-bin/getvalue.exe?value"

then i get a response value, i.e. 1234, which is shown in a blank browser window.

with the following ajax call i get the response value in firebug -> network -> response tab (1234). but i can't access the value in javascript. console.log(data) just returns "undefinded".

is there a way to catch the value with javascript?

i think i have to send ajax request as dataType: "script" because a password (cookie) must be send to the CGI as well. if i choose dataType: "text" the password from cookie is not send in the request header.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://otherdomain/cgi-bin/getvalue.exe?value",
        crossDomain: true,
        cache: true,
        dataType: "script",
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(jqXHR);         
        }   
    });
```

Comment: The `dataType` property is the expected data type of the **response**, not the request. If you leave it blank, it uses the "best guess" default, whereby jQuery attempts to guess the type based on the format of the response.

Comment: if i coose a different dataType than    script    the password is not send to the server.

Comment: if i coose a different dataType than **script** the password is not send to the server. the request header **Cookie: pwd=xxxx** is only sent when i choose dataType: "script" in ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) AJAX doesn't allow cross domain requests, except those that have a response of type `JSONP`. You'll need to set up a proxy on your server to query using AJAX, which submits the request to the other domain then returns the response that it receives to the AJAX call.

Comment: my websert anser with Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *. So cross domain is not the problem.